# Statistically, what are the determinants of which particular religion someone will follow?

Tags: statistics, religion

I can look at data on smokers and recent ex-smokers to identify what variables correlate with success in quitting, or relapse. I can adjust for covariates, or leave the analysis unadjusted. I did a spot of Googling and coudldn't find analogues findings from the psychology of religion at the level of different denominations, although there were studies about religious behaviour, non-specific to particular faiths. Has this work been done, and if so, what are the determinants? If the work hasn't been done, which datasets are best suited for that?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you share some of the sources that you have found? They may help a potential answerer to find and formulate his/her answer.